# create a new rule in jsp page for if condition

Tags: java, jsp

I want to create a jsp page such that i can calculate the grade for a paricular student

I have a jsp page where i can select the student name and enter the mark for subject wise .

```
eg:
<table>
<tr>
<td>Student name</td><td><select><option value="">Pooja</option><option value="">Rani</option></select>
<td>Subject <select><option value="" selected >Maths</select>
<td>Mark</td>
<td><input type="text ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Student name</td><td><select><option value="">Pooja</option><option value="">Rani</option></select>
<td>Subject <select><option value="" selected >English</option></select>
<td>Mark</td><td><input type="text ></td></tr>
</table>
```

Now how to create a logical condition such that if Pooja has 80 marks in english and 80 in maths , only then grade is B. I mean how to dynamically create an if condition. alos how to add a logical operator in front end

Comment: You sure you want to do that inside the presentation layer (JSP?) Not maybe in the backend (Servlet?) after submitting your form?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) library.

```
<c:if test="${grade gt 80}">
    //your code here
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional statements in jsp as follow:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Java Code Geeks Snippets - Condition Content in JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <%
        if ("myvalue".equals(request.getParameter("myparam"))) {
    %>
        This will be printed if parameter myparam equals with myvalue
    <%
        } 
        else {
    %>
        This will be printed if parameter myparam DOES NOT equal with myvalue
    <%
        }
    %>

</body>
```

Comment: I am going to add a condition dropdown like this <table>
<tr>
<td>Student name</td><td><select><option value="">Pooja</option><option value="">Rani</option></select>
<td>Subject <select><option value="" selected >Maths</select> <td><select><option value="'>==</option><option>!=</option>
<td>Mark</td>
<td><input type="text ></td></tr>. Now next to first condition i need to add a plus icon to add logical operators &&  || to check if both conditions are satisfied. how to do it pls help

Comment: are you getting your values from database?

Comment: Only the student names  i am getting from db. Condition operator i am hardcoding

Comment: get your db result in resulrset and aplly your if condition afterr getting value from the resultset                                                                             <select>
        <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
            <option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
        </select>